# Props from grand parent component always assigned using first value of the grand parent map

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
const Card = () => {

    const data=[
            .......................
            ]

    return (
        <div class="mx-auto">
            {data.map((item, index) => (
                <Cardi key= {index}  index={index} angkatan={item.nama} tanggal={item.tanggal} dtanggal={item.detail_tanggal} items={item.jumlah_peserta} limit={item.limit_peserta} periode={item.periode}/>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Card;
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import Registerform from "./registerform";



const Cardi = (props) => {




        return (
            <div class="card w-96 bg-base-100 shadow-xl mx-auto mb-8 mt-8">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <Registerform periode= {props.periode} />
                </div>
            </div>

        )
}



export default Cardi
```

```js
const RegisterForm = (props) => {


    const modalRef = useRef();

    const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
        name: yup.string().required("Nama harus diisi!"),
    });

    const handleSubmit =  async  (values, { setSubmitting }) => {


        let insert = {
            nama: values.name,
            periode: props.periode
        }
        console.log(insert)

        try {
            const response = await axios.post("https://gingonic.vercel.app/api/createpeserta", insert, {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });

            console.log('Response:', response);

            setSubmitting(false); // Menghentikan status submitting form

            toast.success("Pendaftaran Berhasil!", {
                duration: 1500,
                position: "top-right",
            });
            modalRef.current.checked = false;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            alert('Terjadi error periksa duplikasi data')
        } finally {
            ///window.location.reload()
        }

    }



    return (
        <div className="card-actions justify-end ">
            <Toaster position="top-right" />
            <label htmlFor="my-modal-3" className="btn btn-primary">Isi Form</label>

            {/* Put this part before </body> tag */}
            <input type="checkbox" id="my-modal-3" className="modal-toggle" ref={modalRef}/>
            <div className="modal">
                {/*<div className="modal-box relative h-3/6">*/}
                {/*//<label htmlFor="my-modal-3" className="btn btn-sm btn-circle absolute right-2 top-2">✕</label>*/}
                <Formik
                    initialValues={{
                        name: "",
                    }}
                    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                    validationSchema={validationSchema}
                >

                    {({ errors, touched, isSubmitting }) => (
                        <Form className="modal-box relative h-4/7">
                            <label htmlFor="my-modal-3" className="btn btn-sm btn-circle absolute right-2 top-2">✕</label>
                            <label htmlFor="name">Nama</label>
                            <Field
                                type="text"
                                id="name"
                                name="name"
                                className={`input input-bordered w-full max-w-10xl mb-4 ${
                                    errors.name && touched.name ? "input-error" : ""
                                }`}
                            />
                            <ErrorMessage
                                name="name"
                                component="div"
                                className="text-red-600"
                            />
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary"  disabled={isSubmitting}>
                                {isSubmitting ? "Mengirim data..." : "Kirim"}
                            </button>
                        </Form>
                    )}
                </Formik>
            </div>
            {/*</div>*/}
        </div>

    );
};

export default RegisterForm;
```

Why props value on `props.periode` always assigned into first value of the grand parent (`Card`) component.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: show your `data`, and looking at your codes, multiple Cardi is being rendered, are all the Cardi rendered with the first item of data? Can you change the in `.map` of Card component to something unique rather than index?

Comment: the cardi rendered with different items but the registerform always rendered with the first value of item